# Links under a custom select not redirecting on declared page from hidden li

Tags: html, css

I have a strange problem with a custom select. I used a simple "ul li ul" to create that select and it expand on focus but if I want to use some links when select is expanded on that hidden li's when I click on them nothing happens and I don't understand why :|

if someone can help me with this.

Fiddle example: **http://jsfiddle.net/RwtHn/1128/**

Answer (score 1):

The default target for the link(_self) didnt work.  (dont know why) 
Try with _blank or _parent

```
   <ul id="main">
        <li class="username" tabindex="1" >  <a>USERNAME</a>
            <ul class="curent_buser">
                <li><a  href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nOGsB9dORBg" target="_blank">HELP NEEDED</a></li>
                <li><a wicket:id="logoff" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nOGsB9dORBg" target="_blank">LOG OFF</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

​

Comment: I think the offending part is #main li.username:active ul{
    display: none;
} Can you use javascript to show/hide?

Comment: check this out http://jsfiddle.net/BauDc/2/ If you add blur event here, then you will face the same issue as before. its the blur/focus event thats causing issue (NOTE: i never used MooTools before. there may be a better way to achieve the same)

Comment: Rajani Karuturi with js is easy to fix that but I don't want to use any js :|